# Stubbing e.preventDefault() in a jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I recently added an `e.preventDefault()` to one of my javascript functions and it broke my jasmine spec. I've tried `spyOn(e, 'preventDefault').andReturn(true);` but I get `e` is undefined error. How do I stub `e.preventDefault()?`

```
showTopic: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  midParent.prototype.showTopic.call(this, this.model, popup);
  this.topic.render();
}

it("calls the parent", function() {
    var parentSpy = spyOn(midParent.prototype, "showTopic");
    this.view.topic = {
      render: function() {}
    };
    this.view.showTopic();
    expect(parentSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Did the solution not work?

Comment: @Asad no, that was why I deleted it

Comment: Your `spyOn(e, 'preventDefault')` is ok but you didn't pass `e` to the `showTopic()` in the `it()`. Is that the point?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Another way to create mock object (with spies you need) is to use `jasmine.createSpyObj()`. 
Array containing spy names have to be passed as second parameter.

```
var e = jasmine.createSpyObj('e', [ 'preventDefault' ]);
this.view.showTopic(e);
expect(e.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 2):

don't know this approach is correct or not but works for me, feel free to tell if it is not a good approach

step1:create a eventStub with the function for prevent default

```
 const eventStub = {
      preventDeafult() {}
    }
```

step2: write the 'it' Block:

```
it('should preventDefault when dragover event occurs', () => {
  // step 3 goes here
  // step 4 goes here
  // step 5 goes here
});
```

step3:create spy for prevent default:

```
const spy = spyOn(eventStub, 'preventDefault');
```

step4:trigger the event let's say dragover and pass the eventStub

```
  component.triggerEventHandler('dragover', eventStub)
```

step5:write the assertion

```
expect(spy).tohaveBeenCalled()
```

Note: "component" in step 4 is the instance of component we get from fixture
Example to get component instance from fixture:

```
let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(<your Component's Class Name>);
let component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

try and let me know if it works for you thanks you,,,, Happyyy coding :-) !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an object with a field preventDefault that holds your spy:

```
var event = {preventDefault: jasmine.createSpy()}
this.view.showTopic(event);
expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to approaches on top. I just mocked out the event and passed preventDefault with an sinon spy.  The difference was that I had to identify the type which was a click on my test.

```js
var e = {
    type: 'click',
    preventDefault: sinon.spy()
};
```